# Javascript document.getElementById(arg) -object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have a function that set selected = true. I have a dropdown list of countries. Each option has ids such as USA, GER...

```
    function nation(arg) 
{
    if (arg == '<?php echo $this->escape($this->user->get( 'country' ));?>')
        document.getElementById(arg).selected = true;
}

window.onload = nation('<?php echo $this->escape($this->user->get( 'country' ));?>');
```

I'am sure that php code returns me the correct country, but javascript debugger says:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'selected': object is null or undefined
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Send relevant generated Javascript code at client side, not server-side scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `nation` **immediately** and then assigning its return value to `onload`, so you are almost certainly calling it before the `<select>` has been added to the DOM.

You need to assign a function.

```
window.onload = function () {
    nation('<?php echo $this->escape($this->user->get( 'country' ));?>');
};
```